# Php replace strings with "invisible chars" (\n)

Tags: php, replace, textarea

i get from db a text like this.

```
{br}{/br}hello!{br}{/br}
```

this text is outputted inside a textarea element.

what i need is to replace all the `'{br}{/br}'` with invisible char `'\n'` which should set a enter space in the textarea itself. hoping :)

what i tryed to do is.

```
$text = str_replace('{br}','\n',$text);
        $text = str_replace('{/br}','\n',$text);
```

then output `$text` in textarea, but chars `\n` are visible :|

Comment: `/n` will add a line-feed, not a space (I guess that's probably what you want though).

Comment: yep i mean i need the char for a enter space in text area and i'm trying using \n, but somenthing wrong, cause i literal see the \n in textarea and breakline is not added :|

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php Read this, it states '\n' and "\n" are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str_replace`](http://us.php.net/str_replace) with a double quoted `"\n"` for it to be interpreted as a newline; `'\n'` with single quotes is a literal backslash followed by an `n`.

```
$text = str_replace('{br}{/br}', "\n", $text);
```

I'm not sure why you're calling `str_replace` once for `{br}` and once for `{/br}`. Do you want each pair of `{br}{/br}` to be replaced by two new lines? If so, you could do that more simply with a single call:

```
$text = str_replace('{br}{/br}', "\n\n", $text);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the `\n` in double quotes, not single quotes. Variables and escape sequences are not interpolated in single quotes. Also, you probably want to replace the whole string `{br}{/br}` with a single new line - with what you have done you will replace it with two.

So:

```
$text = str_replace('{br}{/br}',"\n",$text);
```

Is probably what you want. It's probably worth you reading [this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php) so you know what you can/can't do with strings in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

Try using double quotes

```
$text = str_replace('{/br}', "\n", $text);
```